# Google Apps: Using google apps as external SMTP server

Tags: smtp, google-workspace

I was using their SMTP servers on my php application, but after 1 march they have changed their rules and account were suspended for violation of rules. I haven't found anything i could violate. O_o

I was using free version of google apps. Maybe if i'll buy a subscription i'll help? Quota was at 0%, don't know what happened...

Can anyone help please?

There are mostly private messages, registration messages etc. Some banners inside mails.

People paying for ads on a website and we send them notification about sms payment, maybe this violates their rules?

Can google apps in commercial project?

Answer (score 0):

You have been suspended on March 1, it doesn't mean its due to new rules. Its just coincidence.
If you really never involved in spamming, following one or more reasons may be responsible:

- Your server's IP had poor reputation.
- Your emails contained links pointing to websites having poor reputation.
- You were sending malicious codes with emails.
- Many users in Google network reported your most of emails as spam.

Contact support to re-enable your account. Maybe, they could ask you for real-world identities.
Google apps wasn't designed for such things. For bulk emailing, I recommend you to use [Mail Chimp](http://mailchimp.com) type services. [Mail Chimp](http://mailchimp.com) is free for upto 2000 subscribers and it provides nice API which can be used by your PHP application.

Comment: As a supporting statement, read their TOS, it's pretty self explanatory. You can use Google Apps just fine for transactional emails, see how many are allowed per hour. The stricture comes about for bulk mailing. If you are using GA for promotional mailings and advertising, you're breaking TOS. Find someone like iConnect, MailChimp or go set up a phplist account. Don't use any of them for cold call unsolicited emailing (bought lists, email addresses that have been scraped, customers who haven't asked for UCE) or you will be breaking their TOS as well.